# I'm unable to extract the Data from this XML

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I'm currently working on a small weather application in C#. To do this, I need to extract data from this xml file: http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22london%22&format=xml

In this specific case I need the value of the first /query/results/place/woeid node. I've been looking around and tried many different methods, but didn't manage to get any values with any of those. My current code looks like this:

```
string query = String.Format("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22london%22&format=xml");
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(query);

XmlNodeList nodeList = wData.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/query/results/place");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
{
    return node.SelectSingleNode("woeid").InnerText;
}
return "NO WOEID FOUND!";
```

I'm just starting to learn C# so I might do some stupid mistakes. Still, I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: My suggestion would be to deserialize this xml document into a class and use that class's properties to access the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XDocument

```
string query = String.Format("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20geo.places%20where%20text%3D%22london%22&format=xml");
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(query);
XNamespace ns = "http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/schema.rng";
var woeid = xml.Element("query").Element("results").Elements(ns + "place").FirstOrDefault().Element(ns +"woeid").Value;
```

Make sure you check if there are any  elements in the XDocuments

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Really appreciate the fast answer.